# English translation for Dutch Randstad?

Tags: translation

The four major cities in the Netherlands, i.e. Amsterdam, Rotterdam, The Hague and Utrecht belong to the Randstad. What is the English translation for the Dutch word Randstad? I have found downtown but I wonder whether this is the correct translation.

Comment: From the third paragraph on the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Randstad): »Although the name _Randstad_ is often translated into English as "edge city" or "border city", a more accurate translation would be "rim city" […] coined by […] Plesman who […] used it to describe a strip of cities at the rim of a large green agricultural area (the Green Heart). While technically more of a crescent (the southeastern edge of the rim is significantly less populated), the ring shape formed by connecting the four major cities of the region led to the use of the name "Ring City".«

Comment: I would think that *Randstad* would be the most appropriate term.

Comment: I would keep Randstad as well. But, to avoid repetitions, you may refer to "conurbation" (or "urban community").

Comment: @HotLicks and Graffito: I think the question is about a translation of what the name _means_, since it says “the Dutch _word_ Randstad”, rather than “the Dutch _name_ Randstad”.

Comment: The US census might call in "the greater metropolitan area of Amsterdam."

Comment: @HotLicks Could you comment on KeepTheseMind's answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The uncapitalised *randstad* is not a Dutch word.* However, because *rand* (*edge*) and *stad* (*city*) are Dutch words, natural (also given what the *Randstad* is) 'translations' of the Dutch name *Randstad* [would be](https://www.britannica.com/place/Randstad) *Ring City*, *Rim City*, *City on the Edge*.

Of these, *Ring City* certainly looks the most appropriate. And, like [here](http://rjh.ub.rug.nl/ha/article/view/4338/4328), it may be good to put it between inverted commas:

> According to this definition the Randstad - the ‘Ring City’ embracing Amsterdam, Rotterdam, The Hague and Utrecht - is not a European metropolis in the sense that Paris and London are.

The use of the inverted commas indicates that *Ring City* is not the real name, but rather a translation of sorts of *Randstad*.

If used enough over the next couple of hundred years, *Ring City* (without the inverted commas) could become the English version of the name *Randstad*, not unlike *Cologne* is the English (and French) version of the German name *Köln*.

NB: Observe that the Dutch usually speak of *de Randstad*. However, unlike *Den Haag*, the *de* is not part of the name. Which would give *the `Ring City'* in English.

---

*In the sense that it is not in the dictionary. However *randstad* [may be used](http://taaladvies.net/taal/advies/vraag/692/) (by combining *rand* + *stad*) when it means *randgemeente* (*suburb*). However, I've never seen it used as such *and* it would mean something different as it would be a place *bordering a bigger city* (which is not the case for the *Randstad*, which sort-of goes *around* the relatively thinly populated *Green Heart* area).

Comment: What is or isn't a word is a bit of a Pandora’s box to get into, but I'd say _randstad_ quite squarely meets the criteria for being one in Dutch. It's regularly formed, it's instantly understandable, and it's actually used, even if only as a proper noun. It may not be included in Dutch dictionaries, but that doesn't mean it's not a word.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I added some stuff in. Perhaps you agree.

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by the Baltimore-Washington corridor:

> the Dutch metropolitan corridor

(It just happens to be ring-shaped.)

There's also *megalopolis*.

Minneapolis-St. Paul are the twin cities.  Perhaps your four cities could be the *quadruplet cities*.

If the context is clear, you could call it the *doughnut*.  The four cities could be called the *doughnut cities*.